# Is there any ways to recode the following xlrd using openpyxl? I'm told this >> XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, xlsx

```
# Open Excel workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')

# Read leader data

ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Leaders')
leaders = []
for i,t in enumerate(ws.col_values(0)[3:]):
    # Create Leader object
    adultLead = Leader(*ws.row_values(3+i)[:3])
    leaders.append(adultLead)

# Read service data
service = []
for j,b in enumerate(ws.row_values(0)[3:]):
    coveredBy = [t for i,t in enumerate(leaders) if ws.cell_value(3+i,3+j) == 1]
  # Create Service object
    adultService = Service(*ws.col_values(3+j)[:3], coveredBy)
    services.append(adultService)

# Read location data
ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Locations')
locations = ws.col_values(0)[1:]
dist = {(l, l) : 0 for l in locations}
for i,l1 in enumerate(locations):
    for j,l2 in enumerate(locations):
    if i < j:
        dist[l1,l2] = ws.cell_value(1+i, 1+j)
        dist[l2,l1] = dist[l1,l2]

ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Clients')
clients = []
for i,c in enumerate(ws.col_values(0)[1:]):
   for b in services:
     if b.name == ws.cell_value(1+i, 2):
        # Create Client object using corresponding service object
        rowVals = ws.row_values(1+i)
        #print(rowVals)
        adultClient = Client(*rowVals[:2], b, *rowVals[3:])
        clients.append(adultClient)
        break
```

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
> Input In [54], in <cell line: 2>()
>       1 # Open Excel workbook
> ----> 2 wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data.xlsx')
>       4 # Read leader data
>       6 ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Leaders')
>
> File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py:170, in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents,
> ```
>
> encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows,
> ignore_workbook_corruption)
> 167 # We have to let unknown file formats pass through here, as some ancient
> 168 # files that xlrd can parse don't start with the expected signature.
> 169 if file_format and file_format != 'xls':
> --> 170     raise XLRDError(FILE_FORMAT_DESCRIPTIONS[file_format]+'; not supported')
> 172 bk = open_workbook_xls(
> 173     filename=filename,
> 174     logfile=logfile,
> (...)
> 182     ignore_workbook_corruption=ignore_workbook_corruption,
> 183 )
> 185 return bk
>
> ```
> XLRDError: Excel xlsx file; not supported
> ```

Comment: I have uninstalled latest version of xlrd. Reinstalled older version of xlrd==1.2.0. Also used 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data-base0.xlsx')
pd.read_excel(r'data-base0.xlsx', engine="openpyxl"). Not working!!

Comment: if both `xlrd` and `pandas` can't read your file, there might be a problem with the file itself.

Comment: @MB, thanks but my checks indicate that the data is ok

Comment: How do i use openpyxl  instead of xlrd to achieve above objectives?

Comment: wb = op.load_workbook(r'data.xlsx')
ws = wb['Leaders']
print(ws.title)

ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Leaders')
leaders = []
for i,t in enumerate(ws.colums(0)[3:]):
    # Create Leader object
    adultLead = Leader(*ws.row_values(3+i)[:3])
    leaders.append(adultLead)

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [9], in <cell line: 12>()
      8 print(ws.title)
     10 # Read leader data
---> 12 ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Leaders')
     13 leaders = []
     14 for i,t in enumerate(ws.colums(0)[3:]):
     15     # Create Leader object

AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'sheet_by_name'

Comment: The data opens fine... but with callback error 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'sheet_by_name'

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure so did check if xlrd supported xlsx files and it seemed that it did HOWEVER after a little more searching it looks like support for xlsx files has been removed so that would be the reason your file cannot be opened. If you convert to xls then it should open OK.

Comment: The APIs are similar enough that should be able adapt the code to Openpyxl fairly easily. You should update your code accordingly in the question and not comments.

Comment: You've confirmed the file data.xlsx can be opened by Openpyxl. There are some additional changes needed in the code to convert to Openpyxl like 'sheet_by_name'. Are you able to link the file data.xlsx to see what data you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks so much @MB and others for your useful suggestions.
Yes, it's working after installing older version of xlrd as follows:

```
pip install xlrd==1.2.0

# Open Excel workbook
wb = xlrd.open_workbook('data-base0xls.xls')

# Read Leaders data
ws = wb.sheet_by_name('Leaders')
leaders = []
for i,t in enumerate(ws.col_values(0)[3:]):
# Create Leaders object
   thisLead = Leader(*ws.row_values(3+i)[:3])
   leaders.append(thisLead)

thisLead
```

> <**main**.Leader at 0x2437f72e340>